# How to change the desktop shortcut size?

Tags: windows-8

Is there any way to change the size of the shortcuts? I don't mean the padding or font/icon size, I just want the shortcuts to be wider.

[This way](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/change-desktop-icon-size-in-windows-7/) describes how to change it in Windows 7, but I cannot find this link on Windows 8 anymore.

Any suggestions how to change this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change desktop icon spacing in Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/501439/how-can-i-change-desktop-icon-spacing-in-windows-8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> keys to open the Run dialog, type `regedit`, and click/tap on OK.
2. If prompted by UAC, then click/tap on Yes.
3. In regedit, navigate to the location below.

   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics`
4. To Change the Desktop Icon "Horizontal" Spacing

   A) In the right pane of WindowMetrics, double click/tap on IconSpacing to modify it.

   B) Type in a value between -480 to -2730, and click/tap on OK.
   *NOTE*: The default setting is -1125. The minimum amount of space is -480, and the maximum is -2730.
5. To Change the Desktop Icon "Vertical" Spacing

   A) In the right pane of WindowMetrics, double click/tap on IconVerticalSpacing to modify it.

   B) Type in a value between -480 to -2730, and click/tap on OK.
    
   *NOTE*: The default setting is -1125. The minimum amount of space is -480, and the maximum is -2730.
6. When finished, close regedit.
7. Sign out and in of your user account to apply.

Example result:

[image]

Instruction from [EightForums](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9094-desktop-icons-change-horizontal-vertical-spacing-windows-8-a.html) - their copy includes step-by-step pictures.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the icon with your mouse.
2. Press and hold <kbd>Control</kbd>
3. Scroll with your mouse wheel up to enlarge the icons

If you have a touch screen, you should be able to pinch-zoom the icons to  make them bigger (I cannot test as I do not have a touch screen device).

Comment: I already know this option, but I don't mean this. I just want the width to be increased, everything else should stay as it is.

Comment: @BananaBoss you can explain what you mean by the width to be increased? I don't understand.

Comment: I mean this: http://i.imgur.com/puZUw.png

Comment: @BananaBoss Oh. I had no idea that was possible.